# is it possible to slow down VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to slow down each step in my code, it can be handy for some functions like sending keystrokes. I could add "sleep" after each step but is there a better way?

Comment: I was almost tempted to say "sure, just write some code in it"! but I won't....[It's not true..VB.NET is just as fast as c#]

Comment: How about running it on a really slow machine?  Sorry, I'll get my coat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep is seldom a good way to do things. The right way would be to use a timer. Using a timer won't lock up the thread and keep it from processing other events.

Put the keystrokes that you want to send into a list. Then create a timer object that sends the next keystroke available on each tick.

There are several different timer classes available. Which one to use depends on what kind of application you are creating - console, WinForms, WPF?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you...

- only use `Thread.Sleep` from a non-UI thread
- *and* do not get in the habit of doing it on every single thread you create
- *and* can afford to temporarily "suspend" the calling thread
- *and* it is not currently causing any issues

...then I see no practical reason to deviate from what you are doing now. The reason being that other options require code that is more slightly more complex and difficult to read and would not provide any noticeable improvement in performance or resource allocation *if all you are doing is sending keystrokes in a delayed fashion*. This would certainly be one problem where [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) reigns supreme. Do not try to solve a problem that does not exist yet.

Answer (score -2):

Add sleep in your code. Its the practice of the most professionals where slowing down the code is needed. Using Sleep, its in ur hand that how much time you want the compiler to take to execute the next line of code.
I would suggest Sleep function.

Comment: "Add sleep in your code. Its the practice of the most professionals where slowing down the code is needed." - that's bad advice.

Comment: but I think here Sleep would be the ultimate choice. Your comments please

Comment: @Fahad Hussain Sleep is bad solution, because it takes some resources to backup thread state and resume it. And if you add many sleeps, you application can get all the memory from the user machine.

Comment: @VMAtm: Well, pretty much any mechanism for causing a delayed action will cause a context switch of the thread. That would be desirable as compared to a spin wait for example. Even timers at their very core rely on causing on a thread to go into the `WaitSleepJoin` state just like `Thread.Sleep`. The only difference being that multiple timers can be pooled onto a single thread. But, if you only have one timer then the end result won't be much different than using `Thread.Sleep` on one thread. Of course, calling `Sleep` on a UI thread would be really bad, but for a different reason.